# Generate Mapfile

Tags: c++, linker

We have a ELF binary for which I want to generate a map file to find the addresses of functions and other details. But I am getting the below warning via ld. Is the command correct -

```
box 225> ld -M c++_aplication

ld: warning: i386 architecture of input file `c++_aplication' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

I tried with different format [-b] but keep getting the same error. How can I generate a mapfile of the executable? Is it only generated at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Your "c++_application" is an i386 application (32bit).

You are trying to use a 64bit ld to generate your map file. Use a 32bit ld (you can either install a cross-compiler, or do the task on a 32bit linux.